# How to filter list of string lists using string list

Tags: c#, string, list, search, filter

I have a dataview which is filled by an object using string lists. I want pick the suitable entries by typing search words in a textbox.

my object:

```
class my_object
{
    List<string> column1 = new List<string>();
    List<string> column2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> column3 = new List<string>();
    List<string> column4 = new List<string>(); 
}
```

my entries for the dataview:

```
List<my_object> entries = new List<my_object>();
```

My aim is to filter the entries like the search function in the windows explorer but with the difference that i want to include four columns an not just the column with the filename.
Is there any possibility to do this?

What I have tried:

```
internal static List<my_object> SearchObject(this List<my_object> Source, List<string> SearchWords)
{
    List<my_object> results = new List<my_object>();

    foreach (my_object m in Source)
    {
        foreach(string s in SearchWords)
        {
            // Filter Column 1
            foreach(string c1 in m.column1)
            {
                if(c1.IndexOf(s) != -1)
                {
                    results.Add(m);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    return results;

    // Problem:
    // This function only filters the first column.
    // If I want to filter the next column, I have to break all 'foreach' blocks 
    // except the '(my_object m in Source)' block...

    // It the 'break' would work for more the one loop, this method would work...
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the `Contains()` method like

```
foreach (my_object m in Source)
{
    foreach(string s in SearchWords)
    {
        If(m.column1.Contains(s) || m.column2.Contains(s) || m.column3.Contains(s))
        {
             results.Add(m);   
             break;
        }         
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Union all your sublist in a single list and then apply the Any extension to the list of words to search

```
foreach (my_object m in Source)
{
    List<string> allStrings = m.Column1.Union(m.Column2)
                                       .Union(m.Column3)
                                       .Union(m.Column4)
                                       .ToList();
    bool exists = SearchWords.All(x => allStrings.IndexOf(x) != -1));    
    if(exists)
        results.Add(m); 
}
```

However I would test for performaces against a more traditional solution

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.
it works very fast, but unfortunately it only works with whole words and it selects the item where word x OR word y are true. I want to have only the items where word x AND word y are true...

Comment: Well, for the first problem we can replace Contains with IndexOf, the second problem is not very clear. Can you explain what do you mean for word x and word y?

Comment: ok, indexof is clear, and with word x and y i mean the search words

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. _SearchWords_ is a list of string. If you find a word of this list that is contained in any of the sublists of a _my_object m_ you want to add the current _m_ to your results and then pass to the next _my_object_ instance. At this point is useless to search if another word of _SearchWords_ is contained in the same instance of _my_object_ because you have already added the current _my_object m_ to the result list. No, I haven't really understood your problem then.

Comment: i just want to add the **my_object** to the results if every word in the **searchwords** are contained

Comment: Then we can change Any to All

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to refactor you class to allow for searching.  Here's an example that uses indexing:

```
class my_object
{
    class Coordinates
    {
        public int _column = 0;
        public int _row = 0;
        public Coordinates(int row, int column)
        {
            _column = column;
            _row = row;
        }
    }
    List<List<string>> columns = new List<List<string>>(4);
    Dictionary<string, List<Coordinates>> searchIndex = new Dictionary<string, List<Coordinates>>();
    public my_object()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            columns[i] = new List<string>();
        }
    }
    //This will create entries for each consecutive substring in each word that you add.
    public void AddWord(string word, int column)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            int limit = word.Length - i;
            for (int j = 1; j < limit; j++)
            {
                string temp = word.Substring(i, j);
                if (!searchIndex.ContainsKey(temp))
                {
                    searchIndex.Add(temp, new List<Coordinates>());
                }
                searchIndex[temp].Add(new Coordinates(columns.Count, column));
            }

        }
        columns[column].Add(word);
    }
    //This will return a list of list of strings that contain the search term.
    public List<List<string>> Find(string term)
    {
        List<List<string>> outVal = new List<List<string>>(4);
        if(searchIndex.ContainsKey(term))
        {
            foreach(Coordinates c in searchIndex[term])
            {
                outVal[c._column].Add(columns[c._column][c._row]);
            }
        }
        return outVal;
    }
}
```